# AWS Cloudwatch Logs Not Logging /var/ logs Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

As the title suggests, the Cloudwatch Agent on an EC2 running docker is only picking up logs from a couple devices in very specific paths.

We are pushing these two instances with Cloudformation and the config *seems* to be exactly the same. The instance in Frankfurt seems to only be pushing from `/var/lib/docker/overlay2/.../`on one device whereas the one in US is pushing from `/` and `/var` on a few devices

I know this is not super specific. I am not great with Docker (more used to running ECS/EKS on AWS). I know we are using docker-compose and those files are identical. I'm kind of at a loss here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you run through the cloudwatch logs docs or configuration wizard? 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html#cloudwatch-agent-running-wizard

Comment: I have not. I am running through it right now, but I don't think this will solve my problem. The metrics we're trying to collect are custom and I think this only covers most default metrics.

Comment: I took what the wizard did and customized the config.json for the metrics we needed... Still no luck with getting it to pull from the correct path. It is only pulling from overlay on the Frankfurt instance, currently.